# uniform initialization with variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, uniform-initialization

I have a POD `ChParam` and it's a parameter in the variadic template function `set`. I'd like to pass to function arguments(constructor parameters) in curly braces `p.set({ Param::D, 1000.f }, { Param::p, 2000.f })`. And thought that the constructor will be called implicitly and the `ChParam` objects will be created. But it's impossible, I should explicitly create an object `a.set(ChParam{ Param::D, 1000.f }, ChParam{ Param::p, 2000.f });`

is it possible somehow to use the variant `p.set({ Param::D, 1000.f }, { Param::p, 2000.f })`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

using Float = float;

enum class Param : size_t
{
    D = 0,
    p
};
struct ChParam
{
    Param tag_;
    Float value_;
};
class PipeCalcParams
{
private:
    Float D_, p_;
public:
    PipeCalcParams() : D_(0), p_(0) {}
    PipeCalcParams& set_D(Float D) { D_ = D; return *this; }
    PipeCalcParams& set_p(Float p) { p_ = p; return *this; }


    template <typename... Args>
    PipeCalcParams& set(const ChParam& p, Args&&... args) {
        set(p);
        return set(args...);
    }

    PipeCalcParams& set(const ChParam& p)
    {
        switch (p.tag_)
        {
        case Param::D:
            set_D(p.value_);
            break;
        case Param::p:
            set_p(p.value_);
            break;
        }

        return *this;
    }

};

int main() {
    PipeCalcParams a;
    a.set(ChParam{ Param::D, 1000.f }, ChParam{ Param::p, 2000.f });//OK

    PipeCalcParams p;
    p.set({ Param::D, 1000.f }, { Param::p, 2000.f });//error: no matching function for call to 'PipeCalcParams::set(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)' p.set({ Param::D, 1000.f }, { Param::p, 2000.f });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not directly possible to use

```
{ Param::D, 1000.f }
```

as a function parameter when it needs to be deduced.  The reason for this is a braced initializer list has no type.  Since it does not have a type, a type cannot be deduced by the compiler.  You have to help it along.  You can do what you did and specify the type like

```
ChParam{ Param:D, 1000.f }
```

Or you can specify the type of object you are expecting.  If you want a variable numbers of the same types then a [`std::intializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) will work.  It allows the compiler to construct the elements from the individual braced initializer lists.  Using that your code would look like

```
PipeCalcParams& set(std::initializer_list<ChParam> args)
```

And when you call it you would use

```
p.set({{ Param::D, 1000.f }, { Param::p, 2000.f }})
```

Do note the extra set of curly braces used.  The outermost set declares the `std::intializer_list` and each inner set declares each `ChParam` in the list.

Comment: It might be worth noting that since it's a type deduction problem, the OP only needs to specify the type for `Args`, so `p.set({ Param::D, 1000.f }, ChParam{ Param::p, 2000.f });` will work.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I would have but the OP want to be as close to `p.set({ Param::D, 1000.f }, { Param::p, 2000.f })` as possible.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, thanks for info, didn't know about it.=) In this example it will work, but in production code `set` was called in another variadic template function `template<typename... Args>Foo(Args... args) { p.set(std::forward<Args>(args)...) }`. In such case it don't compile.