# incorrect deduction of template parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

The following program does not compile:

```
template <unsigned int dim, unsigned int N, bool P, bool C, class... ParametersType>
void test(ParametersType&&... par)
{
}

int main()
{
    test<2, 3, true, false>(2, 1, {8, 8});
}
```

See it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6351a24abbe7efc3).

The error message

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O1 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:8:41: error: too many arguments to function 'void test(ParametersType&& ...)
 [with unsigned int dim = 2; unsigned int N = 3; bool P = true; bool C = false; ParametersType = {}]'

    8 |     test<2, 3, true, false>(2, 1, {8, 8});

      |                                         ^

main.cpp:2:6: note: declared here

    2 | void test(ParametersType&&... par)

      |      ^~~~
```

indicates that the parameter pack `ParametersType...` is deduced to an empty one, while I would expect it to be deduced according to the types of the arguments passed to `test`.

The problem is in the `{8, 8}` parameter passed to `test`.
Explicitly passing a `std::array` to the function solves the problem:

```
#include <array>

template <unsigned int dim, unsigned int N, bool P, bool C, class... ParametersType>
void test(ParametersType&&... par)
{
}

int main()
{
    test<2, 3, true, false>(2, 1, std::array<int, 2>{8, 8});
}
```

See it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77028f9e0f9aa876).

Why does the compiler apparently incorrectly deduces the pack in the first example?

If the compiler is not able to deduce `{8, 8}` to an `std::array`, I would expect an "impossible to deduce" error. Why instead does the compiler deduce the pack to an empty one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template errors are hard to get right.  It's just a quality of implementation.  Clang for instances gives

```
main.cpp:2:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure 
[with dim = 2, N = 3, P = true, C = false]: deduced incomplete pack <int, int, (no value)>
for template parameter 'ParametersType'
```

which is easier to understand.  And yes, unless using `auto`, [`{stuff}` has no type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640553/uniform-initialization-with-variadic-templates).

Answer (score 3):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

> A braced-init-list is not an expression and therefore has **no type**,
>   e.g. decltype({1,2}) is ill-formed. Having no type implies that
>   template type deduction cannot deduce a type that matches a
>   braced-init-list, so given the declaration template void
>   f(T); the expression f({1,2,3}) is ill-formed.

You can also use `auto` in this context to fix your issue:

```
template <unsigned int dim, unsigned int N, bool P, bool C, class... ParametersType>
void test(ParametersType&&... par)
{
}

int main()
{
   auto x = { 8, 8 };
   test<2, 3, true, false>(2, 1, x);
}
```

Comment: Note that here `x` is a `std::initializer_list<int>`, and not a `std::array`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Exactly!